# How can I ensure the missile stays on the screen when non-spacebar keys are pressed?

Tags: processing

I need to write a Processing program so that "When the user presses the space key a missile is fired from the front of the ship and moves rightwards until leaving the screen.  The user can't fire another missile until the first is off the screen."

What I have written doesn't allow the missile to stay on the screen if other keys are pressed. I have tried adding the function under void keyPressed() with boolean true/false statements which only stopped the whole program from working.

How can I make sure it stays on the page? Also, how can I make sure the player can't shoot another missile until their previous one moves off the screen?

This is the code I have:

```
//global
int ship_y;
int angle;
int missileX;

void setup(){
  size(500, 500);
  ship_y = 10;
  missileX = 55;
}

void draw(){
  background(175);
  fill(50);
  rectMode(CENTER);
  rect(30, ship_y, 50, 25);
  
  //missile moves rightwards after spacebar is pressed
  if (key == ' '){
    circle(missileX, ship_y, 25);
    missileX = missileX + 1;
  }
}

//ship moves down when 's' is pressed and up when 'w' is pressed
void keyPressed(){
  if (key == 's'){
   ship_y = ship_y + 2;
  }
  if (key == 'w'){
    ship_y = ship_y - 2;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please share more details, like the programming language you are using and your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: @NicoHaase I am using Processing. I have tried adding the function under void keyPressed() with boolean true/false statements which only stopped the whole program from working.

Answer (score 1):

Code within the `draw()` function runs every frame.
So every frame, you're clearing the background, drawing the ship, and drawing the missile. Good.

But.
You put the missile drawing code inside this if statement:
`if (key == ' '){`
that only draws the missile if the most recent key pressed was space. So as soon as you you press a different key, `key` is no longer equal to space and your missile doesn't get drawn.

One way to fix it would be to create a variable to indicate whether or not the missile was fired, and use that to determine whether or not to draw the missile (instead of checking the `key` variable).

Like this:

```java
if (missileFired == true){
  circle(missileX, ship_y, 25);
  missileX = missileX + 1;
}
```

Code inside the `keyPressed()` function only runs once each time a key is pressed. This would be a better place to detect when the spacebar is pressed and turn on the `missileFired` flag:

```java
void keyPressed(){
  // code for other keypresses...

  if(key == ' '){
    missileFired = true;
  }
}
```

To detect when the missile goes off screen, you'll just need to check whether `missileX` is greater than the [width of the window](https://processing.org/reference/width.html). `draw()` would be a good place for that, since you probably want to check for it every time the missile moves.

When `missileX` gets larger than the window width, you can reset `missileFired` to false so a new missile can be fired. You'll also need to reset `missileX` to its original position so it originates from the ship position.

Comment: Thank you so much! That makes what I need to do really clear. I have other questions related to this program. Hope I can ask them to you later :)